# Start mobile webapp in fullscreen mode

Tags: jquery, web-applications, mobile, fullscreen

I've the following problem:

I created a webapp using jQuery Mobile 1.2. Now I want to start this app in fullscreen mode without addressbar, toolbar etc.
I already searched the web and find out that there are some meta tags to enable this mode:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

That works correct so far. But I also read that these tags are iOS specific and will ignored under Android.
I thought the framework should switch the mode automatically but it doesn't work. Is there a special global variable that I have to manipulate or a framework function to call or a script snippet to include?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `viewport` is not iOS specific but ..and I'm guessing here.. that the `apple-` are .. *Apple* specific. You probably aren't going to get every browser to behave the same way. In fact I would be upset at my browser for allowing your website to hide the address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this bit of javascript to hide the addressbar in android:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
    window.scrollTo(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your iPhone, open your webpage with Safari.
Next, click on the share button (the one in the middle of the bottom bar).

Then, click on the "on home screen" button.
It will create a bookmark on your home screen.

You just have to launch it, and you have your webapp.

Don't forget to add the code you mentionned in your question.

Comment: I know how to add my app to the home screen, but this is only possible on iPhone. It would be great to have a plattform-independent solution for iOS, Android or Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work on chrome for android:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```